# mysql select one row if no row found with an order

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
'1' AS SITE
, 'test_id' AS ID
, IFNULL(PREV_DATA, 60) AS PREV_DATA
, IFNULL(PREV_DATA + 2, 60 + 2) AS DATA
FROM 'TABLE'
WHERE ID = 'test_id'
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I want only one row even if no row found.
And order is very important.
I tried COUNT(1) or MAX(1), but the result doesn't ordered by create_date...
Please help.

-----ADD SAMPLE DATA

```
+------+---------+-----------+------+---------------------+
| SITE |   ID    | PREV_DATA | DATA |     CREATE_DATE     |
+------+---------+-----------+------+---------------------+
|    1 | test_id |        60 |   62 | 2016-03-21 00:00:00 |
|    1 | test_id |        62 |   64 | 2016-03-21 10:00:00 |
|    1 | test_22 |        60 |   62 | 2016-03-24 00:00:00 |
+------+---------+-----------+------+---------------------+
```

I want below data when the ID is 'test_id'.

```
+------+---------+-----------+------+
| SITE |   ID    | PREV_DATA | DATA |
+------+---------+-----------+------+
|    1 | test_id |        64 |   66 |
+------+---------+-----------+------+
```

And I want below data when the id is 'test33333'

```
+------+-----------+-----------+------+
| SITE |   ID      | PREV_DATA | DATA |
+------+-----------+-----------+------+
|    1 | test33333 |        60 |   62 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: A sample of data would help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look into UNION.. so you adjoin an additional predefined or "blank" row but with the limit 1, it only shows when another row isn't found

something like this (untested):

```
SELECT
'1' AS SITE
, 'test_id' AS ID
, IFNULL(PREV_DATA, 60) AS PREV_DATA
, IFNULL(PREV_DATA + 2, 60 + 2) AS DATA
, CREATE_DATE
FROM 'TABLE'
WHERE ID = 'test_id'
union 
SELECT
'0' AS SITE
, '' AS ID
, '' AS PREV_DATA
, '' AS DATA
, DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -300 YEAR) as CREATE_DATE

ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC
LIMIT 1;
```